# Reuse ListFragment and detail fragment or multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm working on an app that has like ten or more listviews across different activities, each of them uses a different adapter with a different data model and item row layout. 
When you click on a row, the app shows a fragment with the details, nothing new.

My question is about the best approach to do this.

- I could create ten fragments with a listview and ten fragments with a
  details layout.
- Or I could always use the same fragment and use a
  different adapter and inflate a different details layout, depending
  on a TAG, for example.
- Another way for the details fragment could be
  containing all the layouts in one, showing only the one I want and hiding the  rest.
- I also could implement a base fragment and extend it changing the layout in the children.

So my question is not about coding this, is about the cleanest and efficient way to do it.
Is it better to reuse one fragment or have multiple files? 
Is it better to have a lot of files with a little code or a reusable file with a lot of code?

Thanks